# How to restore a replaced file in /bin?

Tags: files, data-recovery

I have created a C program which will sort the array of int given at runtime named 'com'.
And mistakenly typed following command:

```
sudo mv com /bin/cp
```

so now `cp` work as `com` and there is no `cp`, please help.

Answer (score 11):

The output of `dpkg -S /bin/cp` is:

```
coreutils: /bin/cp
```

which means /bin/cp is part of coreutils package. Reinstall it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall coreutils
```

Next time place your custom executables in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: +1 for "Next time place your custom executables in `/usr/local/bin`."